# navigation destination xxx is unknown to this NavController

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a bottomSheetDialogFragment which is being open from HomeFragment(part of navigationcontroller). I wish to open another destination on tapping of a button inside bottomSheetDialogFragment but on doing so it is giving me "destination unknown to this NavigationController"

HomeFragment.kt

```
override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        when (view) {
            binding.ivBacktrack -> {
                val upgradePremBottomSheet =
                    UpgradePremiumMembershipBottomSheetDialogFragment.newInstance()
                upgradePremBottomSheet.show(childFragmentManager, null)
            }
            binding.ivInterested -> displayToast()
            binding.ivNotInterested -> displayToast()
            binding.ivMessage -> {
                val directMessageBottomSheet = DirectMessageBottomDialogFragment.newInstance()
                directMessageBottomSheet.show(childFragmentManager, "Direct Message Bottom Sheet")
            }
        }
    }
```

DirectMessageBottomDialogFragment.kt

```
class DirectMessageBottomDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment(), View.OnClickListener {

    lateinit var binding: LayoutDirectMessageLimitReachedBottomSheetBinding

    companion object{
        fun newInstance(): DirectMessageBottomDialogFragment{
            return DirectMessageBottomDialogFragment()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = LayoutDirectMessageLimitReachedBottomSheetBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        binding.clDmLimitReachedBottomSheet.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(
            context!!, R.color.background_black
        ))
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.tvGetPremiumMembership.setOnClickListener(this)
        binding.tvPurchaseDmPacks.setOnClickListener(this)
        binding.ivClose.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when(v){
            binding.tvGetPremiumMembership -> findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_directMessageBottomDialogFragment_to_paymentFragment)
            binding.tvPurchaseDmPacks -> findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_directMessageBottomDialogFragment_to_dmPackFragment)
            binding.ivClose -> dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide your navigation graph xml file ? The problem  is that you are trying to navigate using an action that its not defined in the navigation graph xml file associated with your BottomSheetDialog. Try to replace `findNavController().navigate()` with `requireView().findNavController().navigate()` and see if it works.